# Working in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that there exists $x$ in $A$ and $y$ in $B$ such that $\mathrm{dist}(A,B)=\|x-y\|$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

Let $A$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $B$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. Prove that there exists $x$ in $A$ and $y$ in $B$ such that $\mathrm{dist}(A,B)=\|x-b\|$.

In a previous question, I was able to prove that $\mathrm{dist}(A,B)>0$. However, I wasn't working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, just an arbitrary metric space. So something about $\mathbb{R}^n$ should give me specific $x$ and $y$. My hint is to use the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You always have a point in the compact set that realises the distance, i.e. with $\operatorname{dist}(A,B) = d(x,B) = \inf \{ d(x,y) : y \in B\}$. Now use the hint to find an $y \in B$ that realises the infimum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

let $(a_n) \subset A$ and $(b_n) \subset B$ with $\|a_n -b_n\| \to \operatorname{dist}(A,B)$  as $n \to \infty$ .  Since $A$ is compact, there is a subsequence (let's call it $(a_n)$) and $a \in A$ with 
$a_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$.  Show $(b_n)$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it has a convergent subsequence.  Since $B$ is closed, that subsquence converges to a point in $B$.  I'll leave the rest to you.

I don't remember what the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem is.  I may indeed be using it in my hint.  EDIT: see comment below.  Also note that if $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint, this proof still works.  The conclusion is vacuous in this case, and there is a trivial proof, but the proof above also works, and it is always nice to remove unnecessary assumptions from any mathematical theorem/problem/lemma etc..

Comment: “Every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a convergent subsequence” is commonly known as the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. `;-)`